# Achieving the best possible compression with data consisting of 0s and 1s?

Tags: c#, compression

I am trying to achieve the best possible compression for data that consists of just 1s and 0s in a matrix.

To demonstrate what I mean, here's a sample 6 by 6 matrix:

```
1,0,0,1,1,1
0,1,0,1,1,1
1,0,0,1,0,0
0,1,1,0,1,1
1,0,0,0,0,1
0,1,0,1,0,1
```

I'd like to compress that into an as small string or byte array as possible. The matrices I will need to compress are bigger though (**always 4096 by 4096** 1s and 0s).

I suppose it could be compressed quite heavily, but I'm not sure how. I'll mark the best compression as the answer. Performance does not matter.

Comment: How about compressing them into bits first and then applying any good compression algorithm on the resulting bits? You would then have to compress 2 MB of random bytes.

Comment: [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) might suite you well.

Comment: Does the end result have to be a string? `byte[]` would make more sense.

Comment: Bytes are okay. I can convert that to strings anyway.

Comment: The effect of (any) compression will depend mostly on the entropy in the data. Chances are you won't get far below 2MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to compress string into other strings even though your data really is binary. I don't know what the best compression algorithm is (and that will vary depending on your data) but you can convert the input text into bits, compress these and then convert the compressed bytes into a string again using base-64 encoding. This will allow you to go from string to string and still apply a compression algorithm of your choice.

The .NET framework provides the class [`DeflateStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) that will allow you to compress a stream of bytes. The first step is to create a custom `Stream` that will allow you to read and write your text format. For lack of better name I have named it `TextStream`. Note that to simplify matters a bit I use `\n` as the line ending (instead of `\r\n`).

```
class TextStream : Stream {

  readonly String text;

  readonly Int32 bitsPerLine;

  readonly StringBuilder buffer;

  Int32 textPosition;

  // Initialize a readable stream.
  public TextStream(String text) {
    if (text == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
    this.text = text;
  }

  // Initialize a writeable stream.
  public TextStream(Int32 bitsPerLine) {
    if (bitsPerLine <= 0)
      throw new ArgumentException();
    this.bitsPerLine = bitsPerLine;
    this.buffer = new StringBuilder();
  }

  public override Boolean CanRead { get { return this.text != null; } }

  public override Boolean CanWrite { get { return this.buffer != null; } }

  public override Boolean CanSeek { get { return false; } }

  public override Int64 Length { get { throw new InvalidOperationException(); } }

  public override Int64 Position {
    get { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
    set { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
  }

  public override void Flush() {
  }

  public override Int32 Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) {
    // TODO: Validate buffer, offset and count.
    if (!CanRead)
      throw new InvalidOperationException();

    var byteCount = 0;
    Byte currentByte = 0;
    var bitCount = 0;
    for (; byteCount < count && this.textPosition < this.text.Length; this.textPosition += 1) {
      if (text[this.textPosition] != '0' && text[this.textPosition] != '1')
        continue;
      currentByte = (Byte) ((currentByte << 1) | (this.text[this.textPosition] == '0' ? 0 : 1));
      bitCount += 1;
      if (bitCount == 8) {
        buffer[offset + byteCount] = currentByte;
        byteCount += 1;
        currentByte = 0;
        bitCount = 0;
      }
    }
    if (bitCount > 0) {
      buffer[offset + byteCount] = currentByte;
      byteCount += 1;
    }
    return byteCount;
  }

  public override void Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) {
    // TODO: Validate buffer, offset and count.
    if (!CanWrite)
      throw new InvalidOperationException();

    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      var currentByte = buffer[offset + i];
      for (var mask = 0x80; mask > 0; mask /= 2) {
        if (this.buffer.Length > 0) {
          if ((this.buffer.Length + 1)%(2*this.bitsPerLine) == 0)
            this.buffer.Append('\n');
          else
            this.buffer.Append(',');
        }
        this.buffer.Append((currentByte & mask) == 0 ? '0' : '1');
      }
    }
  }

  public override String ToString() {
    if (this.text != null)
      return this.text;
    else
      return this.buffer.ToString();
  }

  public override Int64 Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
  }

  public override void SetLength(Int64 length) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
  }

}
```

Then you can write methods for compressing and decompressing using `DeflateStream`. Note that the the uncompressed input is a string like the one you have provided in your question an the compressed output is a base-64 encoded string.

```
String Compress(String text) {
  using (var inputStream = new TextStream(text))
    using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream()) {
      using (var compressedStream = new DeflateStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        inputStream.CopyTo(compressedStream);
      return Convert.ToBase64String(outputStream.ToArray());
    }
}

String Decompress(String compressedText, Int32 bitsPerLine) {
  var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(compressedText);
  using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    using (var outputStream = new TextStream(bitsPerLine)) {
      using (var compressedStream = new DeflateStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        compressedStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
      return outputStream.ToString();
    }
}
```

To test it I used a method to create a random string (using a fixed seed to always create the same string):

```
String CreateRandomString(Int32 width, Int32 height) {
  var random = new Random(0);
  var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  for (var i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
      if (i > 0 && j == 0)
        stringBuilder.Append('\n');
      else if (j > 0)
        stringBuilder.Append(',');
      stringBuilder.Append(random.Next(2) == 0 ? '0' : '1');
    }
  }
  return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Creating a random 4,096 x 4,096 string has an uncompressed size of 33,554,431 characters. This is compressed to 2,797,056 characters which is a reduction to about 8% of the original size.

Skipping the base-64 encoding would increase the compression ratio even more but the output would be binary and not a string. If you also consider the input as binary you actually get the following result for random data with equal probability of 0 and 1:

```
  Input bytes: 4,096 x 4,096 / 8 = 2,097,152
  Output bytes: 2,097,792
  Size after compression: 100%
```

Simply converting to bytes is a better than doing that following by a deflate. However, using random input but with 25% 0 and 75% 1 you get this result:

```
  Input bytes: 4,096 x 4,096 / 8 = 2,097,152
  Output bytes: 1,757,846
  Size after compression: 84%
```

How much deflate will compress your data really depends of the nature of the data. If it is completely random you wont be able to get much compression after converting from text to bytes.

Comment: Would it improve results to take 8 bits (1s and 0s) and convert them to a byte, and then compress the final byte array?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen: That's what I'm proposing.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... as small as possible is not really possible without knowing the problem domain.

Here's the general approach:

1. Represent the ones and zeros in the array using bits not bytes or characters or whatever.
2. Compress using a general purpose loss-less compression algorithm. The two most common are:
   Huffman encoding and some type of LZW.

Huffman can be mathematically proven to provide the best possible compression of data, the catch is in order to decompress the data you also need the Huffman tree which may be as big as the original data. LZW gives you compression equivalent to Huffman (within a few percent) for most inputs, but performs best on data with repeating segments such as text.
Implementations for the compression algorithms should be easy to come by (GZIP uses LZ77 which is an earlier slightly less optimal version of LZW.)

A good implementation of compression algorithms using modern algorithms go to 7zip.org. It's open source and they have a C API with a DLL, but you'll have to create the .Net interface (unless someone already made one.)

The non general approach:
This relays on a known characteristic of the data. For example: if you know most of the data is zeroes you can encode only the coordinates of the ones.
If the data contains patches of ones and zeros they can be encoded with RLE or two dimensional variants of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to create your own algorithm for specifically compressing this data will most likely not yield much.

```
Create a GZipStream with Max CompressionLevel
Run a 4096x4096 loop
 - set all 64 bits of a ulong to bits of the array
 - when 64 bits are done write the ulong to the compressionstream and start at the first bit again
```

This will very easily add your cube into a pretty compressed block of memory

Answer (score 0):

Using [Huffman Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) you can compress it quite much:

```
0  => 111
1  => 10
,  => 0
\r => 1100
\n => 1101
```

Yields for you example matrix (in bits):

```
10011101 11010010 01011001 10111101 00111010 01001011 00110110 01110111
01001110 11111001 10111101 00100111 01001011 00110110 01110111 01110111 
01011001 10111101 00111010 0111010
```

If the commas, line feed and carriage return can be excluded then you only need a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) to store each value. Although now you need to know the dimension of the matrix when decoding. If you don't then you could store it as an int and then the data itself if you're planning on serializing the data.

Something like:

```
var input = @"1,0,0,1,1,1
              0,1,0,1,1,1
              1,0,0,1,0,0
              0,1,1,0,1,1
              1,0,0,0,0,1
              0,1,0,1,0,1";

var values = new List<bool>();
foreach(var c in input)
{
  if (c == '0')
    values.Add(false);
  else if (c == '1')
    values.Add(true);
}

var ba = new BitArray(values.ToArray());
```

then serialize the BitArray. <strike>You'd probably need to add the number of padding bits to properly decode the data</strike>. (4096 * 4096 is divisible by 8).

The BitArray approach should get you the most compression unless there is a significant amount of repeating patterns in the matrix (yes I'm assuming the data is mostly random).

Comment: You can't know how much up front. It could even become bigger.